# rails console で　モデルにtitleを付けれない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ドットインストールでのつまずきです。 
http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_rails_v2/24906

rails consoleのコマンドでの編集を行う際に

p = Project.new(title: "p1")

とタイトルをつけたところ

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: title

というエラーメッセジが。

検索をかても理解できる記事が見つからず、
属性が不明というキーワードまでいきましたが、モデルが上手く生成できていないという意味なのでしょうか?

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Project.new.attributes と入力するとどうなりますか？

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant Project
っていうメッセージがでました。

Comment: 間違えました。 
{"id"=>nil, "titele"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
このような値が帰ってきました。

Comment: もう解決したようですが、上記でも「titele」と表示されているので typo なのが判断付きますね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

モデルを作ったときにカラム名を間違えていませんか。db/migrate/*_create_projects.rbを確認してみてください。

Comment: 解決しました。
原因モデルを生成した時に、カラム名をtitleではなくtiteleという単純なミスでした。皆さんありがとうございます。